# Simplest way to modify a URL in a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Our site contains href links to various subdomains: foo.mysite.com, bar.mysite.com. For testing purposes, I'd like to run the site on a completely different main domain name, and point to subdomains off the new domain name.

Rather than manually change all the links, I'd like to have only one version of the site with links that look like this:

```
<a href="foo.(window.location.hostname)/mypage?myparam=value">Link</a>
```

What's the simplest syntax for doing this?

I know I could write jQuery code to hijack links, but a simpler in-link syntax would be better.

Comment: Relative urls won't handle the subdomains.

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: One subdomain uses Java, another PHP. Yes, I could do this server-side, but then all my pages would have to be dynamically generated. Some of them are plain .html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you use javascripts onclick event ? tpo do this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.href = 'foo.' + window.location.hostname + '/mypage?myparam=value';">Link</a>
```

Comment: @Trevor oh sry i didn't see you posted a similar idea =)
, and why cant i comment on your answer ?

Comment: This appears to be the most compact syntax, and answers the question most directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try on click:

```
<a href="foo.{host}/mypage?myparam=value"
   onclick="this.href=this.href.replace('{host}', window.location.hostname)">Link</a>
```

Comment: Slick. Similar to my jQuery link-hijacking idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen back-end systems use an `ENV` variable to make changes between production environments. For example, you would set an environment variable, like `var ENV = 'live'` or `var ENV = 'production`. You could then use that to define what subdomain to use.

```
var ENV = 'production';

// set subdomain based on ENV variable
var subdomain = 'bar';
if(ENV == 'production'){
   var subdomain = 'foo';
}

// modify every link to use the subdomain
$('a').each(function(){
  var modifyHref = 'http://' + subdomain + $(this).attr('href')
  $(this).attr('href', modifyHref);
});
```

**I don't think you should be doing this on front-end JS though.**

If subdomains are an issue, I would set all the paths to `<a href="/mypage?myaparam=value">`. That way, it won't matter what the subdomain. If you are on the foo subdomain, it will go to "foo.whatever/mypage?myaparam=value", and if you are on the bar subdomain, it will go to "bar.whatever/mypage?myaparam=value".

Comment: I agree with the relative paths. Only thing to notice is that, when referencing secure pages, you do need to add the `https://<domain>/mypage` part

Comment: On doing it server-side: yes, it's possible, but it means all pages have to be dynamic.

Comment: On relative urls: they don't work if the foo subdomain points to the bar subdomain. That's the core problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easy way for such a simple, global testing change is to do a search/replace on your whole site. If you want to proceed with your plan, I would use a server side language such as PHP, if possible. It will be much more foolproof for what you want.